# Why is tidyr::unnest_wider so much slower?

Tags: r, data.table, tidyverse, tidyr

I want to parse a JSON to a data.frame. Possibly the JSON doesn't contain all values. My minimum example shows two ways, one using `tidyr::unnest_wider`, one using `data.table::rbindlist`.

```
rm(list=ls())
library(tibble)
library(tidyr)
library(data.table)

n <- 10000

# Example data - parsed from a json-text-stream, possibly sparse
data <- list()
for(i in seq(n)) {
  if(i%%7==0) {
    l = list(
      b=i*i/n,
      c=exp(-i/100)
    )
  } else {
    l = list(
      a=i,
      b=i*i/n,
      c=exp(-i/100)
    )
  }
  data[[i]] = l
}

# Using the tidyverse way
t0 <- Sys.time()
d1 <- tibble::tibble(json=data) %>% tidyr::unnest_wider(json)
t1 <- as.numeric(Sys.time()-t0,units="secs")
paste("This took",t1,"seconds.") %>% message()

# Using the data.table way
t0 <- tic()
d2 <- data %>% data.table::rbindlist(fill=T)
t1 <- as.numeric(Sys.time()-t0,units="secs")
paste("This took",t1,"seconds.") %>% message()
```

The data looks like this after parsing:

| a | b | c |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0.0001 | 0.9900498 |
| 2 | 0.0004 | 0.9801987 |
| 3 | 0.0009 | 0.9704455 |
| 4 | 0.0016 | 0.9607894 |
| 5 | 0.0025 | 0.9512294 |
| 6 | 0.0036 | 0.9417645 |
| NA | 0.0049 | 0.9323938 |
| 8 | 0.0064 | 0.9231163 |
| 9 | 0.0081 | 0.9139312 |
| 10 | 0.0100 | 0.9048374 |

The output is:

```
This took 3.77877902984619 seconds.
This took 0.0209999084472656 seconds.
```

Why is `tidyr::unnest_wider` so much slower?

Edit: In my application n can be as large as 10^6, 10^7, that's how I found out about the bottleneck.

Comment: `data.table` almost always has the edge with big data. In the source of `rbindlist` it's calling a C function: `.Call(Crbindlist, l, use.names, fill, idcol)`, whereas `tidyr` does everything in R.

Comment: I thought that the tidyverse has been catching up since a long time with C functions, especially dplyr, but also other packages?

Comment: dplyr and tidyr are generally getting faster, but ... sometimes changes introduce slowdowns ([dplyr#6674](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/6674) and `case_when`). Their design goals are very different. I know there is a little synergy, especially wrt the `dtplyr` package, but even that has its limitations.

Comment: When running on my computer I get timings of 0.5s vs 0.01s. I suppose for the tidyverse there's a limit to how fast they need to make it to handle realistic data in a non-frustrating way. I use tidyverse in day-to-day work and switch to data.table for big data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`unnest_wider` is a R function including a loop on columns and calling many other R functions (`col_to_wide`,`unchop`,`unpack`, ...).

Such functions can't compete with a C implementation like `data.table`, see [why](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Performance.html).

To view source code, just type :

```
tidyr::unnest_wider
```

```
function (data, col, names_sep = NULL, simplify = TRUE, strict = FALSE, 
    names_repair = "check_unique", ptype = NULL, transform = NULL) 
{
    if (!is.data.frame(data)) {
        abort("`data` must be a data frame.")
    }
    check_present(col)
    cols <- tidyselect::eval_select(enquo(col), data)
    col_names <- names(cols)
    if (!is.null(names_sep) && !is_string(names_sep)) {
        abort("`names_sep` must be a single string or `NULL`.")
    }
    if (!is_bool(strict)) {
        abort("`strict` must be a single `TRUE` or `FALSE`.")
    }
    for (i in seq_along(cols)) {
        col <- cols[[i]]
        col_name <- col_names[[i]]
        data[[col]] <- col_to_wide(col = data[[col]], name = col_name, 
            strict = strict, names_sep = names_sep)
    }
    data <- unchop(data, all_of(cols))
    for (i in seq_along(cols)) {
        col <- cols[[i]]
        data[[col]] <- df_simplify(x = data[[col]], ptype = ptype, 
            transform = transform, simplify = simplify)
    }
    unpack(data, all_of(cols), names_repair = names_repair)
}
```